# Возможно ли выполнить код INF файла в C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

Подскажите, есть ли возможность выполнить INF-файл внутри приложения?

Или выполнить все тоже самое, только через код C#

Код файла INF ([защита MBR](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/MBRFilter/releases)):

```
; MBRFilter.inf
;

[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class     = DiskDrive
ClassGUID = {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Provider  = %csco%
DriverVer=09/21/2016,11.39.10.746
CatalogFile=MBRFilter.cat

;
; General installation section
;

[DefaultInstall]
CopyFiles = @MBRFilter.sys
Addreg    = MBRFilter.AddReg

[DefaultInstall.NT]
CopyFiles = @MBRFilter.sys
Addreg    = MBRFilter.AddReg

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12

[MBRFilter.AddReg]
HKLM, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-8002be10318}, UpperFilters, 0x00010008, MBRFilter


;
; Service installation section
;

[DefaultInstall.Services]
AddService = MBRFilter, , MBRFilter.Service.Install

[DefaultInstall.NT.Services]
AddService = MBRFilter, , MBRFilter.Service.Install

[MBRFilter.Service.Install]
DisplayName    = %service_desc%
ServiceType    = 1
StartType      = 0
ErrorControl   = 1
ServiceBinary  = %12%\MBRFilter.sys
LoadOrderGroup = "PnP Filter"

[SourceDisksFiles]
MBRFilter.sys=1

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %diskid1%,,,

;
; Localizable Strings
;

[Strings]

csco         = "Cisco Talos"
service_desc = "MBR write filter"
diskid1      = "Cisco Talos MBR filter"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно попробовать через `Process` запустить в инсталляторе `InfDefaultInstall`, запуск процесса лучше обернуть в блок `try...catch`:

```
var pathInf = "C:\\MBR.inf"; // путь к вашему inf файлу 
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c C:\\Windows\\System32\\InfDefaultInstall.exe " + pathInf;

try
{
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // ex.Message - будет хранить текст возникшего исключения
}
finally
{
    process.Dispose();
}
```

А еще нашел вот такой способ запуска (для начала импортировать):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport(
    "Setupapi.dll", 
     EntryPoint="InstallHinfSection",
     CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void InstallHinfSection(
    [In] IntPtr hwnd,
    [In] IntPtr ModuleHandle,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string CmdLineBuffer,
    int nCmdShow);
```

А затем вызов:

```
InstallHinfSection(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "путь к .inf файлу", 0);
```

Ссылка на источник: [install/uninstall an .inf driver programmatically using C# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032515/5275890)

Comment: Так и просится using, либо try/finally.

Comment: @klutch1991 - да, лучше запуск процесса выполнять в блоке `try...catch`, естественно. Вы правы, дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Наверное,  klutch1991 имел в виду, что явный вызов Dispose не нужен. Достаточно использовать блок using.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight - ну тут на выбор, либо вызвать явно `Dispose()`, либо использовать `using`.